# Mysql Count distinct IDs in Sum(if())

Tags: mysql

I have following tables.

Case

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Anton |
| 2 | Elfriede |
| 3 | Osram |

Appointments

| ID | Duration | Case |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 70 | 1 |
| 2 | 70 | 2 |

Fastdocu with out appointment

| ID | Duration | Case |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15 | 2 |
| 2 | 15 | 2 |
| 3 | 50 | 3 |
| 3 | 8 | 3 |

I need sum up all duration and all appointments and the cases that are not in Appointments.

The result should be

Duration     88 
Appointments 3  
Cases        1

Following Statement I have written

```
Select sum(duration), count(DISTINCT ID), SUM(IF(`Case` NOT IN (1,2),1,0)) From Fastdocu
```

Suddenly the result is

Duration     88 
Appointments 3
Cases        **2**

I must sum only distinct ids at the cases count. But the distinct seems to be forbidden in the if.
How can I count the cases right?

Comment: `CASE` is a [reserved word in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html). Enclose it in back-ticks to use it as an identifier.

Comment: Have added the escaping. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `COUNT()` with a `CASE` expression instead of `SUM()`:

```
SELECT SUM(duration) total_duration, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT ID) distinct_ids, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN `Case` NOT IN (1,2) THEN `Case` END) cases_not_in_Appointments 
FROM Fastdocu
```

Since `COUNT()` does not have an `ELSE` branch it will not count `Case`s that do not satisfy the condition `Case NOT IN (1,2)` because in this case the result of the `CASE` expression will be `NULL`.

If you want to count the distinct `id`s and not the distinct `Case`s change to:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN `Case` NOT IN (1,2) THEN ID END)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=63da1c05e937557061324b9d80021bd3).
Results:

> | total_duration | distinct_ids | cases_not_in_Appointments |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 88 | 3 | 1 |

Comment: Upvoted, but this could use some explanation. The `CASE` expression without an `ELSE` clause returns NULL when no expression is matched and `COUNT()` ignores NULLs.

Comment: @BillKarwin fair point. I added a brief explanation.

Comment: Maybe we can use double the cases so it looks like  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN `Case` NOT IN (1,2) THEN `Case` END CASE WHEN `Case` IN (1,2) THEN 0 END )

Comment: @Collie-ITAnneK.Frey this is syntactically wrong. Why do you want the 2nd CASE?

Comment: Okey I have miss understand the else sentence of the answer.